# How to pass argument to shell script file from servlet

Tags: java, shell, servlets

I am trying for GUI application where in I need to pass values to run shell script functions and these values are passed from `JSP to Servlet` and `Servlet to shell` file.

*Can any one please suggest how to execute this?*

Answer (score 0):

Using the usual java way.
Suppose parameter is param

```
String shCmd = "sh test.sh "+param;
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(shCmd);
```

Take care of script path.
This code can be placed in jsp as well as servlet. Its just Java.

Comment: I will try for this. Thank you!!

Comment: I have one more question.. after passing the value how to retrieve it in shell script?